# Entering the UK as a visa-free visitor while work visa in in progress

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, uk-visa

I will soon start a job in the UK under a "skilled worker visa". Unfortunately, the visa process takes longer than anticipated, but my future employer is okay with delaying my start date as long as it takes. I am a EU citizen, and there is effectively zero chance of being denied the visa, the paperwork just takes time.

Question: Can I enter the UK as a tourist and effectively have a vacation until my work visa and job starts? After all, my housing in the UK is already paid for anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General considerations answer (check what applies to EU citizens traveling to the UK):

- What first needs to be checked here is the formalities to accomplish after entering the UK and beginning to work (in terms of residence/work permit, medical insurance, etc.) You might be required legally to enter with your work visa and have it stamped/validated at the entry point. This wouldn't prevent you from vacationing - you will just have to leave the UK and re-enter with the appropriate visa.
- A practical consideration is whether you have an appropriate travel document on hand - that is your passport is not in the embassy or, if it is, that you are allowed to enter the UK without passport, e.g., with the EU identity card.